# Wordpress query_posts displayed by category custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields, advanced-custom-fields

Have wordpress based site, where:

- MainCategory

  - Subcategory(custom-field value = custom1)
  - Subcategory2(custom-field value = custom2)
  - Subcategory3(custom-field value = custom3)
- MainCategory2

  - Subcategory(custom-field value = custom1)
  - Subcategory2(custom-field value = custom2)
  - Subcategory3(custom-field value = custom3)
- MainCategory3

  - Subcategory(custom-field value = custom1)
  - Subcategory2(custom-field value = custom2)
  - Subcategory3(custom-field value = custom3)

As you can see, all subacegories in main categories are the same. With same name (not slug), and there are custom fields with same field values.

I need to display posts that is in `MainCategory2` **AND** `subcategory has custom field with value custom2`. Is this possible?

P.S. I use ACF plugin for custom fields.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but it will hopefully solve your problem.

1. Loop all posts of MainCategory2 (let's assume, this category has the ID 2)
2. Check if the content of the custom-field is equal custom2.
3. Define what should be looped (in this example it's the blogtitle and link)

The code would look like this:

```
<?php query_posts( 'showposts=20&cat=2&order=ASC' ); ?>
   <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

      <?php if( get_field('custom-field') == 'custom2' ): ?>
         <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br />
      <?php else : ?>
      <?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: Definitely a bad solution unfortunately :-). `showposts` is depreciated and never ever use `query_posts`, it is slow, reruns queries and breaks the main query object